# How To render properly a component in react useEffect and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I am trying to get instantly data from my Firebase with onSnapshot and it is working.
But the input field got the same amount of data in the Firebase as [object object],[object object] if I have two data in the Firestore. If I want to add data then when I click on the input field, the page becomes white.
I can't add new data this way.
Any help, please?

codesandbox.io ==> https://codesandbox.io/s/long-bush-sjkjnq?file=/src/Body/AppBody.jsx

```
function AppBody() {
  const [reservation, setReservation] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
  db.collection('reservations')
  .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
  .onSnapshot(snapshot =>(
    setReservation(snapshot.docs.map(doc =>({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data()
    })))
  ))
  },[])

  const handleClick = ()=>{
  if(!reservation){
    return;
  }
  db.collection('reservations').add({
    title: reservation,
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),

  })
  setReservation("");
  }

  return (
  <div className="appBody" >
    <div className="appBody__left">
      <h3>Reservations: </h3>

      <div className="reservationCard">
      {reservation.map(({id, data: {title}}) =>{
          return <ReservationCardItem 
          key={id}
          id={id}
          title={title}
          Icon={CloseIcon} />
        })}
      </div>

      <div className="reservationInput">
          <input type="text" placeholder="reservation name" value={reservation} 
  onChange={(e)=>setReservation(e.target.value)}  />
          <button onClick={handleClick} >Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="vertical__line"></div>

    <div className="appBody__right">
        <h3>Menus: </h3>
        <div className="menu__card">
            <div className="menuCard__person">
              <h4>Selena gomez</h4>
              <CloseIcon />
            </div>
            
            <div className="menucard__menu">
                
              <ReservationCardItem title="Selena" Icon={CloseIcon} />
              <ReservationCardItem title="Selena" Icon={CloseIcon} />
            </div>

            <div className="menuCard__input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="add Menu item" />
              <button>Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
  }

  export default AppBody
```

Comment: Do you mind reproducing your issue in https://codesandbox.io/? it becomes a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: [object object], is usually displayed when you mistakenly pass an object (read ref) type to a text display field instead of a value type.I see in your case, at ` <input type="text" placeholder="reservation name" value={reservation}` you are passing `reservation` which is your state. I assume this is probably not what you intended to do. you are also initialising your state to an array, but then setting it to a string later (`setReservation(e.target.value)` so things are a bit messy. Perhaps reproduce in codeSandbox so we can assist further.

Comment: this is the Link of codesandbox.io :  https://codesandbox.io/s/long-bush-sjkjnq?file=/src/Body/AppBody.jsx

Comment: I guess you are reading the input directly to the firestore. I suggest you first read the input first to your memory and then write it to the firestore.

Comment: I created another piece of state (like a copy), so that i didnt use the initial state directly. and it worked. i don't know if it was the better solution, but  it worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I created another piece of state (like a copy), so that I didn't use the initial state directly. And it worked.
I don't know if it was the better solution, but it worked fine :)